# Integrating Netlify CMS with existing static website

Tags: content-management-system, netlify, netlify-cms

I have a simple static website written with HTML, CSS, JS (with jQuery). Is it possible to integrate netlify CMS with my project? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you have flat files for data storage.